# Data for spectrum of Wolf-Rayet stars

Tags: star, spectroscopy, resource-request

I'm looking for a way to access the data used to produce [these plots](http://www.astronomie-amateur.fr/ProjetsSpectro3_WRAtlas_Lisa.html) for instance. These plots show the spectrum of various Wolf-Rayet stars. I found a few websites where you have some informations on those stars [here for instance](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-ref?querymethod=bib&simbo=on&submit=submit+bibcode&bibcode=1987ApJS...65..459T), but I'm not able to find and download a file containing the spectrum data of the stars.

Comment: Depending on the number of digits precision you need, you could take the graphs and feed them to DataThief   https://datathief.org/

Comment: Thank you @CarlWitthoft, I did not know this tool. That can be very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know how to reduce raw spectrum data, you may look at the official archives of big observatories (ESO, MAST, CADC). But a quicker and much easier way could be to use the following portal:

http://archive.eso.org/scienceportal/home

Typing the name of some Wolf Rayet stars will lead you to reduced data and thus spectra.

Comment: Thank you, the eso website is a very nice reference that I did not know!